# Reversing a Matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, rags-to-riches

I took the idea from [Reversing a matrix in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/66791/18427) and decided to write my own matrix-reversing code.

Is there anything that I can do to make it even better?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var matrix = new[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
        };

        PrintMatrix(ReverseMatrix(matrix));
        Console.ReadLine();

        var matrix2 = new[,]
        {
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {9,10,11,12},
            {13,14,15,16}
        };
        PrintMatrix(ReverseMatrix(matrix2));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    static int[,] ReverseMatrix(int[,] inputMatrix)
    {
        var outputMatrix = new int[inputMatrix.GetLength(0), inputMatrix.GetLength(1)];
        var x = 0;
        for (int i = inputMatrix.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var y = 0;
            for (int j = inputMatrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                outputMatrix[x, y] = inputMatrix[i, j];
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        return outputMatrix;
    }
```

I stole the `Print` method from the other question. I imagine that I could place it inside the original loop if I wanted to write fewer lines of code, but I think that might violate the SRP.

Comment: This doesn't work with matrices that are not `X by X`

Comment: Your question is a target of [rags-to-riches](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66847/matrix-reloaded-or-reversed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it more clear that `x` and `y` must move together with `i` and `j`,
move their declarations and manipulations inside the loops, right next to each other:

```
static int[,] ReverseMatrix(int[,] inputMatrix)
{
    var outputMatrix = new int[inputMatrix.GetLength(0), inputMatrix.GetLength(1)];
    for (int x = 0, i = inputMatrix.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; i--, x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0, j = inputMatrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j >= 0; j--, y++)
        {
            outputMatrix[x, y] = inputMatrix[i, j];
        }
    }
    return outputMatrix;
}
```

This way it's less error-prone, easier to read, and more compact, all at the same time.

I would move `ReverseMatrix` method into a `MatrixUtils` class,
and rename it to simply `Reverse`.
Since it becomes perfectly clear that you're working with matrices,
I would also simplify the parameter and local variable names,
as `inputMatrix` and `outputMatrix` seem kind of tedious.

It would be better to replace the uninteresting `Main` method with unit tests on the example matrices:

1. Easy way for you (and for code reviewers) to verify the implementation works
2. The assertions in the tests would clarify the definition of "reverse matrix"

Comment: Next step on this project....Unit Tests! and a more OO Approach!

Answer (score 6):

> is there anything that I can do to make it even better?

Yes, you should use a more OO approach, where you should

- Define a class `Matrix`
- Add a `Reverse()` method which returns a `Matrix`
- Override the `ToString()` method for getting a `String` representation for printing

You can then easily extend the class, like adding the ability to multiply 2 matrixes etc.

Comment: Also he can represent the matrix as a regular 1D array. That will increase performance.

Comment: Implementation: http://pastebin.com/PRc22th4